# Setup SCM Plugin fails with remote hung up unexpectedly

Tags: rundeck

I am not able to set up SCM import or export to my repo on Bitbucket. I did not have such an issue before, in other words, I configure my project SCM exactly the same as on my current instance, but for a new RD instance that runs on RHEL 8.6 I get an error.
Please help.
My repo is setup with ssh access key

**Failed cloning the repository from ssh://git@stash.ilabs.io:7999/qaiac/rd-draftpaper.git: ssh://git@stash.ilabs.io:7999/qaiac/rd-draftpaper.git: remote hung up unexpectedly**

```
apiversion : 41
base : /var/lib/rundeck
build : 4.6.1-20220914
buildGit : v4.6.1-0-gc78ff2c
```

Log file

```
[2022-10-03T21:15:17,193] ERROR transport.TransportImpl [sshj-Reader-stash.ilabs.io/199.119.122.142:7999] - Dying because - Session has timed out waiting for authentication after 120000 ms.
net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: Session has timed out waiting for authentication after 120000 ms.
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.gotDisconnect(TransportImpl.java:533) ~[sshj-0.33.0.jar:?]
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.handle(TransportImpl.java:489) [sshj-0.33.0.jar:?]
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:113) ~[sshj-0.33.0.jar:?]
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.received(Decoder.java:200) ~[sshj-0.33.0.jar:?]
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:60) [sshj-0.33.0.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a [known issue](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/7857), the solution is to regenerate the keys in [this](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/7rgfVchMkQE/m/C7LkcfEIAAAJ) (ed25519 format) way.

Comment: yes, thank you. I got it working with ed25519 key pair